# Get the actual width of an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have a footer with an an image located on the right side.  Below is an abstract sample of said footer.

The problem is, whenever the page becomes too wide for the window and horizontal scrolling becomes active, my footer's width continues to stay dependent on the width of the body, instead of the actual width of the content.

```
<body>
<div id='bodyContent' style="height:600px; width:600px;">
    <div style="width:200px; height: 400px; float:left; background-color:pink ">
    </div>
    <div style=" margin-left:220px; width:1000px; height:500px; background-color:green; padding:1px;">
        <div style="width:200px; height:100px; margin:74px; background-color:lime;"></div>
        <div style="width:1200px; height:100px; margin:74px; background-color:lime;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='footerContent' style="min-width:100%; padding:0; background-color:black; height:150px; margin: 100px 0 0 0; position:relative;">
    <div id="image" style="width:75px; height:75px; position:absolute; right:37px; bottom: 37px; background-color:yellow;"></div>
</div>
```

Is there some css or javascript that can be applied to this so that I can set the width of my footer to the actual width of the web page?  I have checked document, window, and screen width/outerwidth; but each one fails to handle the overflow size of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

//this will get the actual `width` or `height` of the specified element

```
<div id='bodyContent' style="height:600px; width:600px;">

<div style="width:200px; height: 400px; float:left; background-color:pink"></div>

<div style=" margin-left:220px; width:1000px; height:500px; background-color:green; padding:1px;">

<div style="width:200px; height:100px; margin:74px; background-color:lime;"></div>

<div style="width:1200px; height:100px; margin:74px; background-color:lime;">
<!-- Added this element as a check -->
<div style="width:5000px; height:100px; margin:74px; background-color:lime;"></div>

</div>

</div>

</div>

<div id='footerContent' style="min-width:100%; padding:0; background-color:black; height:150px; margin: 100px 0 0 0; position:relative;">

<div id="image" style="width:75px; height:75px; position:absolute; right:37px; bottom: 37px; background-color:yellow;"></div>

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
//this returns the actual `width` and `height` of the specified element (excluding `borders`) 
function getActualWH(el){

    return {aW:el.scrollWidth,aH:el.scrollHeight}

    }
```

//if you want the border's width included, than you can use one of my previous functions ->

```
function getElProps(el,attr){

//checking if the browser is Internet Explorer    
isIEX = navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/);

whaT_ = isIEX ? el.currentStyle : window.getComputedStyle(el);

getWhaT_ =  isIEX ? whaT_.getAttribute(attr) : whaT_.getPropertyValue(attr);

    return getWhaT_;

}
```

**Example (without borders):**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8LZgp/9/)

```
var element = document.getElementById('bodyContent');

width = getActualWH(element).aW;
height = getActualWH(element).aH;
```

**Example (with borders):**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8LZgp/12/)

```
width = getActualWH(element).aW;
borderLeftWidth = parseInt(getElProps(element,'border-left-width'));
borderRightWidth = parseInt(getElProps(element,'border-right-width'));
actualWidth = width + borderLeftWidth + borderRightWidth;


height = getActualWH(document.getElementById('bodyContent')).aH;
borderTopWidth = parseInt(getElProps(element,'border-top-width'));
borderBottomWidth = parseInt(getElProps(element,'border-bottom-width'));
actualWidth = width + borderTopWidth + borderBottomWidth;
```

This code also works in IE8 (if you're planning on supporting it)

Comment: Elements within the bodyContent are dynamically generated so specifying the width of the footerContent on startup isn't possible.  Now a min-width would be feasible but only if I can get the actual width of bodyContent.

Comment: @StoicDeveloper, see my edited answer and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: No.  Your result is getting 600px, not the 1000px based on it's inner content.  So if I set the footer to the _width, there would be 400px of whitespace next to my footer when the user scrolls to the right.

Comment: That was pretty good.  And on a simple layout, this would work.  I don't have a simple layout.  See my update.

Comment: You know, I honestly believed your concept would pull up short.  But damn am I impressed.  I had to put conditionals for isNaN() when you got the border widths, but it all works minus a few unknown hiccups on my end.  Thanks for all the help and hanging in there till the end.

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, I checked an hour (or so) ago, to see any results from my answer in this post (was curious if my answer succeeded) and also went on checking whether you were online. And when I saw you recent activity and saw no answer to my post, I thought that something had gone wrong. I'm glad it worked for you!

If you don't mind renaming your post's title to something like "Getting the actual width of the element" or something similar, so if somebody has a similar issue, they won't search long and will be able to find this post easier. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you could put a parent wrapper with the width ilke this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lw54F/

```
<div id='wrapper' style="width:1000px;">
  <div id='bodyContent' style="height:600px;">
    <div style="/*width:1000px;*/ height:250px; background-color:green;"></div>
  </div><div id='footerContent' style="width:100%; padding:0; background-color:black; height:150px; margin: 100px 0 0 0; position:relative;">
     <div id="image" style="width:75px; height:75px; position:absolute; right:37px; bottom: 37px; background-color:yellow;"></div>
```

Comment: I wish that was possible, but based on what I am working with (SharePoint's OOTB Seattle.master), I can't just wrap everything up.  I have to account for elements within my bodycontent container breaking out of the parent width.